# Automatic yes to prompts when installing package on Alpine Linux

Tags: software-installation, alpine-linux

I'd like to know if `apk add` is capable of automatically assuming yes to any prompts when installing a new package on Alpine Linux?

I'm familiar with running something like `apt-get install -y curl` on Ubuntu and wondering if there's an equivalent command for my use case.

Comment: Can't say for sure, but their [documentation](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) doesn't indicate one.

Comment: did you do some tests ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`apk` does not need a `--yes` argument as it is designed to run non-interactively from the get-go and does not prompt the user unless the `-i` / `--interactive` argument is given (and then only for "certain operations").

Ref `apk --help --verbose`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it as I could not find a package prompting me, but either `yes | apk add <package>` (for multiple prompts) or `echo y | apk add <package>` (in case there is only one prompt) should work.

For details see https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Thanks for sharing.